# How can I type function that accepts union type only if it contains specific subtype?

Tags: typescript

How can I generically type the following function `processArray` somehow just by mention that the provided array is of `string[]` subtype without explicitly mention `type1` nor `type2`, for example by `arr: type1 | type2`?

The goal is not get TS error for all four examples of function call in the bottom. See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgA4CcFQKYGdcCC66AhgJ4A8AKstgB4zYQAmuyuM6cEA5gNoBdAHwAKEsQBcyKgEopANwRxmyAN7Bkm5FCS4EAG2wA6fQh5jiMgNzAAvsGA6IHdkXTIAvMj4AiEj4AaZB8AI0DgqB8BGycXCDdPbwBGIIAmIIBmaMddGGQQhK8+TjBsIJASfVxsbJznPPF0JMSAWRIYAAsjUhYEAFsRGWQKZAAGIwBWZAB+V2JkKXjiYAwsPEJicgsm62QAej3aYgR0IJCwPNwOhDB9ZggAcjyQ7AdYhuJU1vaunuZ+wbDMaTGZzdxSArLVY4fBuLaNVK7A5HTCnfIXdjXW73J75V51FyNDLfTrdEi9AZDEbjKazJbg-JuGzQ9ZwsjbDJIw7YY7uEhsbiMFjYZhBXDcHDIInackQBB5VAIfBwEL6Mh4qXsTjcHhSzZkYBAA) for the two calls that returns error.

The reason for this call is that the function will be used in application where there are around ten union types, each with the type that the function will process as its subtype (these types are generated from OpenAPI specification so there could be others in future when specification changes). I wanted to get around the necessity to create a new union type for all of these types or specify them as possible accepted types for the function argument. Ideally I wanted to just specify subtype that function works with.

```
function processArray<T extends string[]>(arr: T): void {
    console.log(arr);
}

const sArr = ["a", "b", "c"];
const nArr = [1, 2, 3];
const bArr = [true, false];

const arr1 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? sArr : nArr
processArray(arr1); // error, but shouldn't be

const arr2 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? sArr : bArr
processArray(arr2); // error, but shouldn't be

const arr3 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? nArr : bArr;
processArray(arr3); // error as intended, since arr3 cannot possibly be a string array
```

Comment: Either `processArray(arr: type1 | type2)` or `processArray<T>(arr: T[])`? I am confused why you would want to do this?

Comment: @jcalz I added link to playground where the issue can be observed and added bit more explanation about what I'm after.

Comment: @jcalz I read through the documentation, checked your playground again and I understand how it works now. TS is not Java types.

Comment: newer TS version (4.9) has this thing called "satisfies operator". could u use it?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator

Comment: @jcalz I changed the playground code. You can write the answer and I will reward you with check mark. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) only serve as a so-called *upper-bound* on a type.  If you have `T extends string[]`, then it requires that `T` is a *subtype of* or *assignable to* `string[]`.  What you want is more like a *lower-bound*, since you want `string[]` to be assignable to `T` instead.  That is, you want it to be a type which can *accept* a string array, not one which can *provide* a string array.  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) asking for this, but so far it's not part of the language.

Actually it sounds like you want a slightly different constraint.  You want `T` to be some array type, so `T extends readonly unknown[]`, and you want the element type of that array to *possibly* be a `string` of some sort.  So instead of saying that the element type is bounded by `string` from above or from below, it's more like you want to say that there is *some overlap* between the type and `string`.  So if an element of the array is `string`, or `string | boolean`, or `"a" | "b" | "c"`, or `"a" | number`, that's all fine.  You only want to reject it if there's no overlap at all, like if the array element type were `number | boolean`.

So we need a way to express that in a constraint.  Luckily we can do so this way:

```
function processArray<T extends readonly unknown[] &
    (string & T[number] extends never ? never : unknown)
>(arr: T): void {
    console.log(arr);
}
```

This is a self-referential constraint (also called [*F-bounded*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)) which happens to be accepted (sometimes TS rejects them as circular).  It says that `T` has to be assignable to `readonly unknown[]`, *and* (using [the intersection])(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), we need it to be assignable to the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `string & T[number] extends never ? never : unknown`.  The type `string & T[number]` is the intersection or *overlap* between `string` and the element type of `T` (if `T` is an array and you [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with a key of type `number`, then you get the element type, so `T[number]`).  If that overlap type is empty, it's [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) and the conditional type evaluates as the accept-nothing `never` type.  If that overlap type is not empty, the conditional type evaluates as [the accept-everything `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).

So, in other words, if `T`'s element type can possibly include a `string` type, the constraint evaluates to `T extends readonly unknown[]`, and it will accept the array... but if it cannot, then the constraint evaluates to `T extends never`, and the whole thing will fail.

Let's test it out:

```
const sArr = ["a", "b", "c"];
const nArr = [1, 2, 3];
const bArr = [true, false];

const arr1 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? sArr : nArr
processArray(arr1); // okay

const arr2 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? sArr : bArr
processArray(arr2); // okay

const arr3 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? nArr : bArr;
processArray(arr3); // error

processArray(["a", "b"] as const); // okay
processArray(["a", 1] as const); // okay
processArray([1, 2] as const); // error
```

Looks good.  Only arrays that don't accept `string`s of any kind are rejected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgA4CcFQKYGdcCC66AhgJ4A8AKstgB4zYQAmuy62JzSANmcpADWEBAHcIAbQC6yAGTBki5AApcMdHAgBzOcioSIYALYAjbOhn1GLNhGwA3c8gD8yO4-TIAXAIjCxEACUwAB8yiTEPlSBPvYIcMzIAN4KSlBIuAg82AB0PAha4cSBANzAAL7AwOkQasiExMgAvMgSAEQkbQA0yG0m3b1QbVJlNXUQRJ4tEgCMPQBMPQDMI9UZMMgmk82t6mDYPSAkPLjYq2u1GxHoMzsAsiQwABY5pCwIRsqByBTIAAw5ACsLnq2x8E2IwAwWDwDVIZCKN1KyAA9CjkAhBOQqmMrsR5vdHi83txPt9fgDga44d5NpMoZgcPhJuREfNkWiMViyDj1shrktCc9XiR3mSfv8gSCIZ4fFtiGVoUy4ayBRz0eZMOgqkrYSyEe1Oj0+sN+WxcequdjdcziKzDQMZjISOb1pbMdbGXq7Qa5sh5s7XZdLZqEOggA)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this:

```
function processArray<T extends string | number | boolean>(arr: T[]): void {
    const [first] = arr;

    if (typeof first === "string") {
        console.log(arr); // some complex logic here
    } else {
        // do nothing for arrays that are not of string[] type
    }
}
```

This allows you to pass arrays like your example values, but also mixed types, so you may need a guarantee in your application that arrays have only one type. Otherwise rewrite your check to (at the cost of some additional computation):

```
if (arr.every(value => typeof value === "string")) {
```

Comment: The check was just example. The actual code contains proper type guard that determines if the type is the expected one or not.

Comment: My goal is to have only the "string" or "string[]" in the function type signature. I don't want to specify names of the other types if possible. There could be a lots of these types and I wanted to get around the necessity to make a union type that would list all the possible types that goes there.

Comment: @xMort in that case you could just accept a generic type `processArray<T>(arr: T[])` and still check if every member is a string